# QT OpenGL Link Error

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I have encountered an error while compiling an OpenGL QT project in QT Creator on Windows.

The error I am getting is a link error.

I have tried re-running qmake, followed by a clean, and build, but this did not solve the issue.  I have also tried some of the other suggestions from stackoverflow questions similar to mine but none resolve this issue

I will include the link error and my project code below.

Thanks in advance!

link errors:

```
17:38:04: Running steps for project OpenGL2...
17:38:04: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
17:38:04: Starting: "C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" 
    C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -f Makefile.Debug
    C:\Qt\5.6\msvc2013_64\bin\uic.exe ..\mainwindow.ui -o ui_mainwindow.h
    cl -c -nologo -Zc:wchar_t -FS -Zi -MDd -GR -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -w44996 -EHsc /Fddebug\OpenGL2.pdb -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I..\..\OpenGL2 -I. -IC:\Qt\5.6\msvc2013_64\include -IC:\Qt\5.6\msvc2013_64\include\QtOpenGL -IC:\Qt\5.6\msvc2013_64\include\QtWidgets -IC:\Qt\5.6\msvc2013_64\include\QtGui -IC:\Qt\5.6\msvc2013_64\include\QtANGLE -IC:\Qt\5.6\msvc2013_64\include\QtCore -Idebug -I. -IC:\Qt\5.6\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\win32-msvc2013 -Fodebug\ @C:\Users\context\AppData\Local\Temp\main.obj.9848.16.jom
    cl -c -nologo -Zc:wchar_t -FS -Zi -MDd -GR -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -w44996 -EHsc /Fddebug\OpenGL2.pdb -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I..\..\OpenGL2 -I. -IC:\Qt\5.6\msvc2013_64\include -IC:\Qt\5.6\msvc2013_64\include\QtOpenGL -IC:\Qt\5.6\msvc2013_64\include\QtWidgets -IC:\Qt\5.6\msvc2013_64\include\QtGui -IC:\Qt\5.6\msvc2013_64\include\QtANGLE -IC:\Qt\5.6\msvc2013_64\include\QtCore -Idebug -I. -IC:\Qt\5.6\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\win32-msvc2013 -Fodebug\ @C:\Users\context\AppData\Local\Temp\mainwindow.obj.9848.32.jom
    C:\Qt\5.6\msvc2013_64\bin\moc.exe -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -D_MSC_VER=1800 -D_WIN32 -D_WIN64 -IC:/Qt/5.6/msvc2013_64/mkspecs/win32-msvc2013 -IC:/Users/context/Documents/OpenGL2 -IC:/Qt/5.6/msvc2013_64/include -IC:/Qt/5.6/msvc2013_64/include/QtOpenGL -IC:/Qt/5.6/msvc2013_64/include/QtWidgets -IC:/Qt/5.6/msvc2013_64/include/QtGui -IC:/Qt/5.6/msvc2013_64/include/QtANGLE -IC:/Qt/5.6/msvc2013_64/include/QtCore -I. ..\mainwindow.h -o debug\moc_mainwindow.cpp
main.cpp
mainwindow.cpp
..\mainwindow.cpp(3) : warning C4100: 'parent' : unreferenced formal parameter
..\mainwindow.cpp(28) : warning C4100: 'h' : unreferenced formal parameter
..\mainwindow.cpp(28) : warning C4100: 'w' : unreferenced formal parameter
..\mainwindow.cpp(52) : warning C4100: 'event' : unreferenced formal parameter
..\mainwindow.cpp(57) : warning C4100: 'event' : unreferenced formal parameter
    cl -c -nologo -Zc:wchar_t -FS -Zi -MDd -GR -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -w44996 -EHsc /Fddebug\OpenGL2.pdb -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I..\..\OpenGL2 -I. -IC:\Qt\5.6\msvc2013_64\include -IC:\Qt\5.6\msvc2013_64\include\QtOpenGL -IC:\Qt\5.6\msvc2013_64\include\QtWidgets -IC:\Qt\5.6\msvc2013_64\include\QtGui -IC:\Qt\5.6\msvc2013_64\include\QtANGLE -IC:\Qt\5.6\msvc2013_64\include\QtCore -Idebug -I. -IC:\Qt\5.6\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\win32-msvc2013 -Fodebug\ @C:\Users\context\AppData\Local\Temp\moc_mainwindow.obj.9848.718.jom
moc_mainwindow.cpp
    link /NOLOGO /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /DEBUG /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS "/MANIFESTDEPENDENCY:type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*' processorArchitecture='*'" /MANIFEST:embed /OUT:debug\OpenGL2.exe @C:\Users\context\AppData\Local\Temp\OpenGL2.exe.9848.4400.jom

**mainwindow.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_glBegin referenced in function "protected: virtual void __cdecl MainWindow::paintGL(void)" (?paintGL@MainWindow@@MEAAXXZ)
mainwindow.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_glClear referenced in function "protected: virtual void __cdecl MainWindow::paintGL(void)" (?paintGL@MainWindow@@MEAAXXZ)
mainwindow.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_glClearColor referenced in function "protected: virtual void __cdecl MainWindow::paintGL(void)" (?paintGL@MainWindow@@MEAAXXZ)
mainwindow.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_glEnd referenced in function "protected: virtual void __cdecl MainWindow::paintGL(void)" (?paintGL@MainWindow@@MEAAXXZ)
mainwindow.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_glFlush referenced in function "protected: virtual void __cdecl MainWindow::paintGL(void)" (?paintGL@MainWindow@@MEAAXXZ)
mainwindow.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_glVertex2f referenced in function "protected: virtual void __cdecl MainWindow::paintGL(void)" (?paintGL@MainWindow@@MEAAXXZ)
debug\OpenGL2.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 6 unresolved externals
jom: C:\Users\context\Documents\OpenGL2\build\Makefile.Debug [debug\OpenGL2.exe] Error 1120**
jom: C:\Users\context\Documents\OpenGL2\build\Makefile [debug] Error 2
17:38:09: The process "C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project OpenGL2 (kit: Desktop Qt 5.6.1 MSVC2013 64bit2)
When executing step "Make"
```

Here is my code and configuration files:

OpenGL2.pro

```
QT       += core gui opengl

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = OpenGL2
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QOpenGLWindow>

#include <QSurfaceFormat>
#include <QOpenGLFunctions>

#include <QtOpenGL>
#include <GL/glu.h>

class MainWindow : public QOpenGLWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

protected:
    virtual void initializeGL();
    virtual void resizeGL(int w, int h);
    virtual void paintGL();

    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event);
    void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event);

private:
    QOpenGLContext* context;
    QOpenGLFunctions* openGLFunctions;

};
```

main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.setTitle("OpenGL Hello World!");
    w.resize(640, 480);
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
{
    setSurfaceType(QWindow::OpenGLSurface);

    QSurfaceFormat format;
    format.setProfile(QSurfaceFormat::CompatibilityProfile);
    format.setVersion(2, 1); // OpenGL 2.1
    setFormat(format);

    context = new QOpenGLContext;
    context->setFormat(format);
    context->create();
    context->makeCurrent(this);

    openGLFunctions = context->functions();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
}

void MainWindow::initializeGL()
{
}

void MainWindow::resizeGL(int w, int h)
{
}

void MainWindow::paintGL()
{
    // Initialize clear color (cornflower blue)
    glClearColor(0.39f, 0.58f, 0.93f, 1.f);

    // Clear color buffer
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Hello World
    // Render quad
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glVertex2f(-0.5f, -0.5f);
        glVertex2f(0.5f, -0.5f);
        glVertex2f(0.5f, 0.5f);
        glVertex2f(-0.5f, 0.5f);
    glEnd();

    glFlush();
}

void MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    paintGL();
}

void MainWindow::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event)
{
}
```

Comment: You're using GL functions without linking against an OpenGL library => `LIBS += -lOpengl32` (or similar) in your .pro file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those are OpenGL functions, you'll need to link against OpenGL32.lib. Add this into your .pro file:

```
LIBS += -lOpenGL32
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This solved the problem!  It is unbelievable, this is a sample project from a book I bought to learn QT and open GL,  Both the qmake file listed in the actual book and the downloaded qmake file are wrong.